# Scraping only text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the text (dynamic) using selenium which is present as mentioned below in website. I searched all over the internet but I got how to scrape a text when it is present in separate div/p/span or any other tag only. Please help if you have any idea.

```
<div class='css-87uc0g e1tk4kwz1'>
    Text
    <span>
        4.5 
        <span> ::before </span>
    </span>
<div>
```

I want to extract only text here but that span tag is not allowing it.

Note:
The value of text is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `div` element using following `xpath` and use `javascript executor` and get the first child value.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.//span[contains(.,'Rating')]]")
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', element).strip())
```

---

Or you can simply replace the value.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.//span[contains(.,'Rating')]]")
print(element.text.replace(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Rating')]").text,'').strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for an idea, but is there more generic way to get the element's text itself while it can be different amount of elements inside that element?

Comment: @Eliyahu : It depends on how the html structured. Java scripts executor found very useful. If the html structure has new line </br> we can use python `splitline()` to get the value.

Comment: @Bidhya Pokharel : Please check the updated answer and let me know how this goes?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the question. There is no static text as ' Rating', I had just wrote it down to show there is some span tag. But I did it using the css class and then replaced the rating (4.5) as you mentioned. Thank you for sharing!!